# Evaluation power modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the best way to evaluate $8^{126}$ mod $9$?

So there is a path for $8^{126}$ :

$8^2 = **8$, 
$8^3 = **4$, 
$8^4 = **6$, 
$8^5 = **8$, 
$8^6 = **4$, 
$8^7 = **6$,

so 126 should end with $**8$. $8$ mod $9$ is $8$.

I am not sure it's the way way to approach it, thanks!

Comment: Hint: $8\equiv -1 \pmod{9}$.

Comment: Hint 2: $\varphi(9)=6$ so if $\gcd(a,3)=1$ then $a^6$ is $1$ mod $9.$

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

•By Euler's theorem,  $8^6\cong1\pmod9$.  Hence $8^{126}\cong(8^6)^{21}\cong1^{21}=1\pmod9$.

•Since $8\cong{-1}\pmod9$, $8^{126}\cong(-1)^{126}\cong1\pmod9$.